# How to add direct local aar dependency for androidTest?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-library, aar, android-productflavors

I know the way using 'flatDir'.
But android studio warn do not use flatDir.

My project is android library.
I add `jniLib` in sourcet and use `implementation files`.

Then, I could add direct aar dependency to my lib and app which use my lib.
But I can't add dependency to androidTest in my android library project.

I want to use `androidTestImplementation` but my project is `multi flavor` build and there is no `API` `flavor[Debug|Release]AndroidTestImplementation` with `files` arguments.

I tried to search the way, but failed.
Now, I use `flatDir` and ignore warning.

How can I solve this problem?